# Joint PMF for an existing function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let (X; Y ) have joint mass function $P(k, n) = \frac {2^{-k}C}{n}$ , for k = 1, 2, .... and
n = 1, 2, , k, and suitable constant C. Compute $E(X|Y = y)$.

Its easy to calculate the $P(X,Y)$ but i am getting confused in calculating $P(Y)$ also what should be the value(range) of X. Can someone please provide some direction?

Since the value of k is from 1 to infinity, i am getting confused on what to take for x since only Y is given. I am new to this topic so any help is appreciated here

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that $Y=y$, the values taken by $X$ are $\boxed{y}$, $\boxed{(y+1)}$, $\boxed{(y+2)}$... Thus:

$$E(X|Y = y)=\boxed{y}\dfrac{2^{-y}C}{y}+\boxed{(y+1)}\dfrac{2^{-(y+1)}C}{y}+\boxed{(y+2)}\dfrac{2^{-(y+2)}C}{y}+...$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{-y}C}{y}\left( y+(y+1)2^{-1}+(y+2)2^{-2}+\cdots\right)$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{-y}C}{y}\left(y(1+1/2+1/4+\cdots)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k2^{-k}\right)$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{-y}C}{y}(2y+2)$$

(due to a classical result : the sum is equal to the mean $p/(1-p)$ with $p=1/2$ for a geometric series beginning at $1$ and with ratio $p$: see the second column of results in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)).

Thus the final result is :

> $$E(X|Y = y)=\dfrac{2^{-y+1}C}{y}(y+1)$$

Remark: I have computed apart $C=2 \ln(2).$